# Does DC become AC through alternating permanent magnets?

Tags: magnet, dc-ac

As the title suggests.

Does direct current running through a circuit become alternating current if it goes through a linear line of alternating magnetic fields of permanent magnets, such as that of a Halbach array?

Comment: DC remains DC. AC may be induced but the DC will remain the same.

Comment: @Transistor's answer is almost certainly correct, but we need a physical sketch to be sure -- unless it's as simple as a wire laying on top of a Halbach array, in which case you need to _edit your question_ with that information, or if the wire is moving with respect to the array in which case you probably need a diagram, and in any case you need to _edit your question_ with that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faraday's laws of electro-magnetic induction came from his realisation that "spatially varying (and also possibly time-varying, depending on how a magnetic field varies in time) electric field always accompanies a **time-varying magnetic field**". In your proposal the magnetic field is static. It does not vary with time so there will be no effect on the current through the wire.